# How can I determine if a jQuery object is deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

If I have a function that sometimes returns a deferred object but sometimes a non-deferred object. How can I tell which one it is?

Comment: "Type checking" implies other aspects :)

Comment: nice one, had the same issue here

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you could also use `jQuery.when` [1]:

> If a single argument is passed to `jQuery.when` and it is not a Deferred, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

With `jQuery.when` you can treat your mysterious object always as deferred:

```
// x could be a deferred object or an immediate result
var x = getMysteriousObject();
// success will be called when x is a deferred object and has been resolved
// or when x is an immediate result
jQuery.when( x ).then( success, error );
```

[1] http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: won't your 'success' handler potentially have different arguments passed to it - depending on if the object was deferred or not? In which case you're still going to have to use duck-typing like what's suggested below.

Comment: @Crungmungus: "If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately. The doneCallbacks are passed the original argument."

Comment: `$.when( { testing: 123 } ).done(function( x ) { alert( x.testing ); // Alerts "123"
});

Answer (score 30):

Since jQuery Deferreds are created by copying the methods of a hidden object instead of calling the new operator on a function, you cannot proof that the object is indeed an instance of jQuery.Deferred. I think you're gonna need to go with Duck-Typing:

> "When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck."
>   – James Whitcomb Riley

Depending on what objects might otherwise be returned (what properties must be expected), check if particular properties / methods are present:

```
var x = getMysteriousObject();
if (x.promise) {
    // Deferred
} else {
    // Not a deferred
}
```

You can detailed this check if required:

```
if ($.isFunction(x.promise)) {
    // Deferred
}
```

or (to distinguish between Deferred objects and other implementations of the Promise interface)

```
if (x.promise && x.resolve) {
    // Deferred
}
```

Comment: Ok, then I think duck-typing is the best way to go. Was worrying about getting a quail instead of a duck. Now think it's not that important. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Niko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965183/315493), I created another implementation that would check if an object is a deferred based on the name of it's properties **but also** on the content of those properties.  I had to do so since an other object of mine had a property named promise.

```
if (typeof value.resolve !== "function") {
  return false;
}
return String(value.resolve) === String($.Deferred().resolve);
```