# Any way to check whether a variable is a real jqXHR?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title already mentions, is there a way to check whether a variable is a real jqXHR?

I mean (imaginary):

```
var resource = $.get('/resource');

if (resource instanceof jqXHR)
{
    // do something
}
```

The actual problem I am trying to solve, is for a modal-plugin I'm working on.

```
$('#element').modal({
    content : function()
    {
        return $.get('/resource');
    }
});
```

And, the `content` variable can be either `string` or `function`. In case of `string`, it will be static, in case of `function` it will be run every time upon opening the modal.

But, I am looking to allow the `content` callback to return either `jqXHR` or `string`. With string it's pretty simple, `if (typeof returned === 'string')`, but what about `jqXHR`?

I know that I could simply check for `string` and in case it's not a `string`, assume it's `jqXHR`, but I want my plugin to be as strong as possible, and disallow working with unexpected types.

Comment: You can check it's properties, for example, if it has done, fail, responseText, promise, and abort methods, you can be pretty sure that it is a jqXHR object. However, all you really care about is whether or not it is a promise object so that you can use .done and .fail. Just test for the `promise` method being defined on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if a jQuery object is deferred?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965065/how-can-i-determine-if-a-jquery-object-is-deferred)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest just checking whether or not it is a promise object. This will make your code more robust in that the user can return a custom deferred object if they need to do something more complex, or they can simply return the jqXHR for the same effect.

```
if ($.type(resource) === "string") {
    doStuff(resource);
} elseif (resource && resource.promise) {
    resource.promise().done(doStuff);
}
```