# Check whether a object is deferred or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, conditional-statements, deferred

I need to check whether a object is `Deferred` or not using `Jquery`, how to check that?

Thanks in advance,

Madhu

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/10965065/1636522.

Comment: I tried already but its showing same issue that`s why i post this question any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic used internally by jQuery's [when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) method is

```
if(object && $.isFunction( object.promise )){
}
```

src: [deferred.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred.js#L102)